# backup user accounts without giving a home directory to them

Tags: rhel, users, useradd

I am reinstalling the older Ubuntu machines with the latest RHEL 6.0 in servers.

I have `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/group` and `/etc/shadow` file backed up for the list of user accounts that I need to create after reinstallation of OS.

I have installed RHEL 6.0 in couple of machines and I need to grant access to the users immediately.

I want to use the `/etc/passwd` and other files into this machine so that the users can start using the server with their user accounts. But, I do not wish to create a `/home/user` directory for the users for couple of reasons.

- The users will be accessing only the partition `/mounts` which
  apparently has the project data.
- I am eventually planning to configure `NFS` and `openldap` at a later stage. So, if I have to provide `home` directory for the users, I need to backup the home directory for the users in all the machines where I gave the local user account for users and put it in the `NFS` server which is a redundant step.

Is it possible to give users access without `home` folder? I have seen machines without `/home` directory using `/` as the home directory. But I am not sure if this is a safe step and I want the users to be **unaware** that their `home` directories do not exist.

**EDIT**

I see the users can be added without creating the home directory for them using the below command.

```
adduser --system --no-create-home USERNAME
```

But my challenge lies in how can I use the same user account as in `/etc/passwd` and other files without creating a home directory? I want the users be able to use their same passwords as in `/etc/passwd` now without a home directory.

Comment: As far as I know, each user who needs to access a Desktop environment must have a home directory writable by their account.

Comment: @JosephR., the users do not need a desktop environment. They just need to be able to login to the server with their username/password and be able to access the machine.

Comment: In this case, you can just make `/` their home directory (and optionally make `/home/user` a link to `/`, but be very careful when removing it later!!).

Comment: Note that `-s /bin/false` will not allow users to log in!

Comment: @JosephR., I changed the `useradd` command. But that is not my main concern. My concern lies in using the same usernames/passwords as in `/etc/passwd` file.

Comment: The passwords are mot probably in `/etc/shadow` rather than `/etc/passwd`. The usernames are OK as long as you don't have duplicate UIDs (you must ensure the target system has no UIDs like the ones in your back up `/etc/passwd`).

Comment: @JosephR., I have backed up that file too. I want a solution like after replacing the original `/etc/passwd`, `/etc/shadow` and `/etc/group` in the newly installed machine with the files I have from the old machine, I need users to be able to access the machine without a `/home` directory.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15040/discussion-between-joseph-r-and-ramesh).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you're using `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/shadow` for user accounts (as set in `/etc/nsswitch.conf` and PAM), then entry in those two files are fully sufficient to create the account. (`/etc/group` may be needed too, for their groups).

All `useradd` does is edit those files. If you edit them yourself with `vipw` & `vigr` and add the user, you've created the account.

`useradd` wil also (optionally) create a home directory as well, basically doing:

```
cp -p /etc/skel /home/newuser
chown -R newuser:newgroup /home/newuser
```

That said, without a home directory, your users will face a lot of challenges, as many files are stored there—

- Editor configuration files
- Authorized keys for ssh
- Shell startup scripts
- Random program configuration files

You could set all their home directories to a single root-owned, mode 0755 (not writable by the users) directory with sane defaults for them.