# ssh into an account which has no home directory

Tags: ssh, key-authentication

As a follow up to my [previous](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/136670/backup-user-accounts-without-giving-a-home-directory-to-them) question, I have decided to create the local user accounts as below.

```
adduser --system --no-create-home USERNAME
```

Now, I would like the local users to be able to access the machines using `ssh`. As per my understanding, `ssh` works as below.

Assuming I have 2 machines (say *alpha* and *beta*).

- From *alpha* machine: `ssh user@beta`
- *alpha's* public key will be present under `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` in *beta* machine.
- *alpha's* private key will be present under `/~/.ssh` in the *alpha* machine.

Now I have planned to implement **no home** for the users. So assuming I `adduser` into *beta* machine without any home for any user, will I still be able to ssh into *beta* from *alpha*?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`~/.ssh/` is just the default location that `sshd` uses to look for incoming user's public keys.  You can configure the location and the file that `sshd` looks for by modifying the `AuthorizedKeysFile` directive in  `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`.  Mine currently looks like:

```
AuthorizedKeysFile     %h/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

The `sshd_config` man page provides a little more detail:

```
 AuthorizedKeysFile
     Specifies the file that contains the public keys that can be used for user authentication.  The format is
     described in the AUTHORIZED_KEYS FILE FORMAT section of sshd(8).  AuthorizedKeysFile may contain tokens of
     the form %T which are substituted during connection setup.  The following tokens are defined: %% is
     replaced by a literal '%', %h is replaced by the home directory of the user being authenticated, and %u is
     replaced by the username of that user.  After expansion, AuthorizedKeysFile is taken to be an absolute
     path or one relative to the user's home directory.  Multiple files may be listed, separated by whitespace.
     The default is “.ssh/authorized_keys .ssh/authorized_keys2”.
```

Just be aware that `sshd` is very particular about the permissions of a user's `authorized_key` file.  You'll want to keep a close eye on your logs if you set this up and run into problems logging in.

Comment: Beware changing `AuthorizedKeysFile` will probably break login for every other user (unless you do some other cleverness). It may be easier to add a minimal home directory, with just the `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`.

Comment: How does it know what the home directory of the user is?  When I change $HOME it doesn't appear to pay any attention to that.

Comment: The home directory is defined in passwd entry of the user.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of changing the global destination of `AuthorizedKeysFile`, you can create a *homeless* users group and set a specific location for it.

You would only need to add a couple of lines to `/etc/ssh/sshd_config/`:

```
Match group homeless
    AuthorizedKeysFile /etc/ssh/authorized-keys/%u
```

*(`%u` is a [ssh config token](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh_config#TOKENS) which is expanded to the local username at runtime)*

and then create the user key:

```bash
sudo -u <username> bash -c "ssh-keygen -t ecdsa -b 256 -f /etc/ssh/authorized-keys/<username> -q -N ''"
```

Comment: For me it throws `Directive 'UsePAM' is not allowed within a Match block` error

Comment: Another kind of error `Missing privilege separation directory: /run/sshd`

Comment: @AlexeySh. Is the `Match` directive at the end of the file?